# Grouping two regular expressions together

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this regex:

```
((?:website.com\/video\/)(\d+))|((?:video_id=)(\d+))
```

And it matches fine with the patterns i need( for example: http://website.com/video/1337,
http://website.com/video/?video_id1337).

However sometimes I may need to extract a token from the url(the token isn't always present),
so an example url would be http://website.com/video/?video_id1337&token=1337video.

I have a separate regex that can extract the token: `/(?:token=)(\w+)/` which works, but I try to group the two regexes together the second one stops work, here's how I'm trying to group them:

```
((?:website.com\/video\/)(\d+))|((?:video_id=)(\d+)|(?:token=)(\w+))
```

How can I properly group them, so they both work?

Comment: Or'ing two regexes returns the result of the first one that matches, not both.

Comment: What operator should I use to get it to return both results?

Comment: Create two longer expressions (ored) that each grab whatever you need. Or one long expression with optional group matching parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking your matching.  What you want to match is:

1. `website.com/video/`, followed by
2. *maybe* `?video_id`, followed by
3. the video's id number, followed by
4. *maybe* a token

This converts to:

1. `website\.com/video/`
2. `(?:\?video_id)?`
3. `(\d+)` (saved to a group)
4. `(?:[?&]token=(.*))?` (either `?` or `&`, with everything after the `=` saved to a group)

The end result:

```
website\.com/video/(?:\?video_id)?(\d+)(?:[?&]token=(.*))?
```

Comment: I still only get match on the basic `http://website.com/video/1337` form. Investigating...

Comment: It's because of a few more typos and accidentally putting an = where it doesn't belong.  Matches all of the desired URLs now

Comment: 1+ Bingo :) That got it. I was using Expresso to analyse and check your expression.

Comment: Yup I was using regexpal.com.  I accidentally put a silly `=` into the final result after `video_id`  :P

Answer (score -1):

Your regex should be

```js
(?:website.com/video/)((\d+)|([?]video_id(\d+))([&]token=(\d+))?)
```

And switch to global search by adding "g" modifier

```js
var result = mystring.match(/(?:website.com\/video\/)((\d+)|([?]video_id(\d+))([&]token=(\d+))?)/g);
```

Comment: After your edit that is now worse. The matches are now incorrect and do not include "video" from the token. Always use a tool like Expresso or regexpal.com to verify your regex results.

Comment: This won't work and is inefficient.  You'd have to escape the `/` characters in the bottom line to prevent a syntax error.  Also, why should `g` be used here?  It looks like he's only matching one URL.

Comment: No, it matches all 3, but gives very poor results. Sorry.